# Why my active objects are not sliding down when the passive rotates?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I'm making a rigid body scene for the first time.
When I rotate the passive plate myself when the timeline is playing, it works and they slide down. But when I give a rotation keyframe to the passive plate and then play the timeline, nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: If it is "passive" it can't rotate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably just need to set the passive "animated"

[image]

"animated" means that the simulation assumes the active or passive object will be transformed during simulation, so to take its future transform into account...